# What can cause Rails 3.1 "= require jquery" to stop working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I'm porting a Rails 3.0.9 app to Rails 3.1.rc5.  My `application.js` is exactly the same as one generated by Rails 3.1 itself:

```
// This is a manifest file ...
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

But when I run my app and look at the `application.js` in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, all I see is:

```
// This is a manifest file ...
//
```

The directives are gone, so it would seem that the file *has* been processed by Sprockets, but the directives have not been replaced by the contents of `jquery` et al.  There are no errors appearing on the server console or in the logs.

Curiously, when I run a `blog` app (you know, the [canonical tutorial app](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)) it works fine (that is, when I examine `application.js` in Firebug, it contains the text of jQuery.)  This would seem to indicate that something in *my* app is somehow interfering with Sprockets.  Has anyone out there heard of such an issue (and hopefully a workaround)?

Here's my setup:

```
$ gem list jquery

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jquery-rails (1.0.12)
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.0.rc5
```

I'm at a loss as to what might be wrong.  I've triple checked my Gemfile; I've run and re-run `bundle install` and `bundle update`; I've tried rc3, rc4 and now rc5;  I'm running Ruby 1.9.2p290.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround: include JavaScript files with the old-skool tag.  For example, in my (Haml) layout:

```
= javascript_include_tag '/assets/jquery.js'
= javascript_include_tag '/assets/jquery_ujs.js'
= javascript_tag 'jQuery.noConflict();'
```

The `/assets/` prefix tells Rails 3.1.x to look on the *asset path*, which includes gems, so you'll get the same files as with Sprockets directives.  But you won't get concatenation or any other Sprockets preprocessing.

Still looking for better solutions.

Comment: I'm seeing the same things. How this thing is on RC5 is beyond me.

Comment: Same here, but on Rails 3.1 stable!